# A Database Tool to check changes happened overnight and upload to MasterDB

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, data-binding, sqlite, embedded-database

HI

I have 5 different database and a Master DB with same Schema .I am looking for a tool which can check any changes( new row insertion ) has happened since my last update and Sync with my  Master DB . Is there any tool available for this

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good case for using [merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx).

Comment: YEAH,its like Replicating Data Between a Server and Clients .Is there any free tools available :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about free tools - but I know of the [redgate's data compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/) which will do this job for you. It's automatable. Having used it for this task I'd strongly recommend it.

As a personal solution, since you're using SQL Server you could iterate the tables (sys.tables), and do an join between DBs and see what needs to be inserted/deleted etc. Sounds like a tedious job though if you reuse Keys. If the keys are not reused then the task is quite simple.